# Comfortable transfer from BVA to Paris center

Tags: transit, france, airport-transfer, paris, bva

I need to get from Paris Beauvais Tille Airport to Paris center. What are my options (times, prices)?

I'll be travelling as two (or three) adults plus two small kids, therefore comfortable options are most important and speed (time) is little more imporant to me than price.

Comment: If speed was more important than price, why did you book a flight to Beauvais rather than one of the actual Paris airports?

Comment: @CMaster Because my home town (small, local) airport is served only by airlines that lands at BVA. No other option and I don't wish to travel from my home town to any other airport. Period. But, there could be a dozen of reasons, why? I could want to fly an airline that lands at BVA, I may like BVA, I may have business north of Paris etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arguably the most commonly used means of transportation to get to/from Beauvais is [the shuttle from/to Porte Maillot](http://www.aeroportbeauvais.com/bus.php?lang=eng). To date the price is:

> Price:         ONE  WAY  per person: €17 at the BUS TICKETS SALE POINT / €15.90 ON LINE
>
> FREE for children under 3 years old (no ticket)     //     3 years old+ 1day: 1 ticket

[The airport webpage on airport connections mentions other options](http://www.aeroportbeauvais.com/acces.php?lang=eng) include TER trains from Gare du Nord, taxis, and a door to door shuttle service operated by [SuperShuttle](http://www.supershuttleparis.fr/en). Note that a taxi to/from Paris will set you back some 100-120€.